# Is an Android ViewParent guaranteed to be a Viewgroup?

Tags: android, android-view

Is there any real case where `View.getParent`() returns an object that is not of type `ViewGroup` ? Or can I safely cast it without checking its type first like in my code sample below ?

```
 if (getParent() == null){
     throw new IllegalStateException("View does not have a parent, it cannot be rootview!");
 }
 ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compare direct and indirect subclasses of [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and [ViewParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html) they look the same (considering ViewGroup itself).

Still it's possible that in some custom library you may get from `getParent()` a `ViewParent` that isn't `ViewGroup`. Is it a real case?

So 
 - if your can't be sure of parent type you'd better check it. 
- in ordinary app you usually understand what parent is or can be - and so you may skip check

Comment: well, you may find out that getParent could return ViewRootImpl instead of ViewGroup, like this: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Answer (score 7):

It's safe. Every single implementation, in the Android SDK, of `ViewParent` is a `ViewGroup`.

But remember that `instanceof` also checks for nullity. You could write :

```
if (!(getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)){
  throw new IllegalStateException("View does not have a parent, it cannot be rootview!");
}
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
```

Comment: Thanks! i know about instanceof checks for nullity, I just want to make different actions for each of these conditions.

Comment: shouldn't it be if **not** instanceof?

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't doing anything fancy, it should be safe. The only unsafe case is when you reach the root of your view hiearchy. The ViewParent will then be a [ViewRootImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java)